# What does 'f' mean before a string in Python?

Tags: python, f-string

I wonder what `f` in `print(f'Column names are {"-".join(row)}')` does.
I tried deleting it and then `Column names are {"-".join(row)}` become normal string.

```
import csv

with open('CSV_test.txt') as csv_file: 
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {"-".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
        else:
            print(f'\t{row[0]} works in the {row[1]} '
                  f'department, and was born in {row[2]}.')
            line_count += 1
    print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')
```

Comment: read this article https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Comment: They are called `f-strings`. Please see the docs for [fstring](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`join` method returns a string in which the elements of sequence have been joined by a separator. In your code, it takes row list and join then by separator `-`.

Then by using f-string, expression specified by `{}` will be replaced with it's value.

Suppose that `row = ["1", "2", "3"]` then output will be `Column names are 1-2-3`.

Comment: Be careful, `'-'.join([1, 2, 3])` throws an `Exception`. `'-'.join(['1', '2', '3'])` reutrns what you expect. I fixed it in your answer

Comment: .join() takes an iterable whose elements must be a string.

Answer (score 25):

This is called f-strings and are quite straightforward : when using an "f" in front of a string, all the variables inside curly brackets are read and replaced by their value. For example :

```
age = 18
message = f"You are {age} years old"
print(message)
```

Will return "You are 18 years old"

This is similar to `str.format` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) but in a more concise way.

Answer (score 5):

String starting with f are formatted string literals.

Suppose you have a variable:

`pi = 3.14`

To concatenate it to a string you'd do:

`s = "pi  = " + str(pi)`

Formatted strings come in handy here. Using them you can use this do the same:

`s = f"pi = {pi}"`

`{pi}` is simply replaced by the value in the `pi`